# Is 是 being used as a measure word in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:

> 现在，中国网民总数已经超过美国人口总数，但美国网购人数占其全部人口的75%，中国则只有25%左右，而且，中国网购消费者年均消费额仅为美国消费者的1/5。于刚认为，这**是**差距， 更是中国电子商务的潜力。

Is '是‘ in 这是差距 working as a 量词？Or should I read 'this is a disparity'?

Comment: Jessica is right. Also: 这是...更是... could be seen as a *pattern*.

Comment: Just curious.. How would you read it otherwise?

Comment: Well, Chinese nouns, I'm told, need 量词 which is why I thought this might be a sneaky use of 是 as a 量词. Failing that, I would have to read 'This is disparity' Or maybe make a (non-existant) new English adjective 'This is disparacious'

Comment: Why would 差距 take 是 as measure word? Since when is 是 a measure word?

Comment: Why did they not write '这是个差距’？ Or is '差距‘ an adjective here, then why did they not write '差距的’？

Answer (score 3):

Not a measure word. Just the usual meaning of "be".